# How can insert legend for color in go.Choroplethmapbox?

Tags: mapbox, choropleth

How can I change the bar to color subtitles?

For example similar: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5K9f.png)

I am using this:.

```
colorscale = ['rgb(0,255,0)', 'rgb(255,255,0)', 'rgb(255,128,0)', 'rgb(255,0,0)']
data_text = "{} : {} Habitantes.".format(data_nome, data_pop)

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson=geojson_rj, 
        locations=df_rj.municipio_geocodigo, 
        z=df_rj.level_alert,
        text=data_text,
        hoverinfo="text",
        zmin=0,
        zmax=3,
        marker_opacity=0.5,
        marker_line_width=1,
        colorscale=colorscale, 
        autocolorscale=False   
    ))     

fig.show()
```

Thanks.